# RabbitMQ SSL connection issue

Tags: php, ssl, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ installed in a CentOS server.
I have created in my apache vhost configuration the necessary entries for SSL and a reverse proxy to run RabbitMQ over SSL. Below is a sample of my apache config:

```
SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/rmq.xxx.com.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/rmq.xxx.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/rmq.xxx.com.bundle
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full
        ProxyPass /api http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15672/api nocanon
        ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15672/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15672/

        <Proxy *>
            AllowOverride All
        </Proxy>
    </IfModule>
```

I can successfully login to RabbitMQ management interface via SSL by going to https://rmq.xxx.com instead of going to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:15672

I use PHP to send jobs to RabbitMQ and I do it using the library php-amqplib [enter link description here](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib)

If I connect to RabbitMQ without using SSL it works fine see code 1 but if I connect to it using SSL see code 2, I get the following error:

---

> stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://rmq.clixwm.com:5672
> (Unknown error) at
> VENDORPATH/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:108

---

```
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPSSLConnection;
define('RABBITMQ_HOST', 'rmq.xxx.com');
define('RABBITMQ_STANDARD_PORT', 5672);
define('RABBITMQ_SSL_PORT', 5671);
define('RABBITMQ_USERNAME', 'rmq_username');
define('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'rmq_passpord');
$rabbitMQConnectionObj = null;
```

Code 1:

```
$rabbitMQConnectionObj = new AMQPStreamConnection(
    RABBITMQ_HOST,
    RABBITMQ_STANDARD_PORT,
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME,
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD,
    '/'
);
```

Code 2:

```
$rabbitMQConnectionObj = new AMQPSSLConnection(
    RABBITMQ_HOST,
    RABBITMQ_SSL_PORT,
    RABBITMQ_USERNAME,
    RABBITMQ_PASSWORD,
    '/',
    ['capath' => '/etc/pki/tls/certs']
);
```

I'm sure my SSL certificates are in `/etc/pki/tls/certs` but I have no idea why this error is happening.

Thanks?

[image]